# Bootstrap Grid with Responsive height for a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using border-right to separate columns in Bootstrap grid. But this vertical line(border-right) breaks when one cell is occupying more height in smaller screen. So basically, I want all cells in a row to occupy same height. Here's a sample of my mark up:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
 <head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <style>
   div.col-xs-7, div.col-xs-1{
    border-right:1px solid black;
   }
   div.row{
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class = "content">
   <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-xs-7 col-md-5">Medical History Unknown</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">n</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">n</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-xs-7 col-md-5">Heart Condition (CHF, Angina, Heart Attack) </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">y</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-xs-7 col-md-5">Anemia</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">n</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">n</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">y</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-xs-7 col-md-5">Epilepsy, Seizure </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">n</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1">n</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note: It breaks in small screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved it with 
display:table; for .container
display:table-row; for .row
display:table-column;float:none; for .col

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
 <head>
  
  <style>
   div.col-xs-7, div.col-xs-1{
    border-right:1px solid black;
   }
   div.row{
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   }
   .TableStyle {
      display:table;
      padding-left:0px;
      padding-right:0px;
     }
   .RowStyle {
    display:table-row;
   }
   .ColumnStyle {
    display:table-cell;
    float:none;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class = "container TableStyle">
   <div class="row RowStyle">
    <div class = "col-xs-7 col-md-5 ColumnStyle">Medical History Unknown</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">n</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">n</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row RowStyle">
    <div class = "col-xs-7 col-md-5 ColumnStyle">Heart Condition (CHF, Angina, Heart Attack) </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">y</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row RowStyle">
    <div class = "col-xs-7 col-md-5 ColumnStyle">Anemia</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">n</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">n</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">y</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row RowStyle">
    <div class = "col-xs-7 col-md-5 ColumnStyle">Epilepsy, Seizure </div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">y</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">n</div>
    <div class = "col-xs-1 ColumnStyle">n</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is occurring because only the `<div>` with the line-break is extending onto a second line, while the other cells are staying on one line.

Since this data is tabular in nature anyway, it might be worth using a [table](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) since a table cell will react to a line-break elsewhere in the row, extending onto a second line even if that particular cell does not need to itself.

Comment: Upvoted for (being correct and) remembering tables are fine for tabular data, just not layout!

Comment: But, tables are not responsive, right? but I want responsiveness.
So shall I use % width for columns or any other way is there?

Comment: Yes, make the table 100% width of its container and it will scale accordingly. A table can be used in responsive websites.

Comment: I found Bootstrap classes "table & Table-bordered" for responsive table.<table class="table table-bordered"><tr><td></td></tr></table>  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables